# Error running context: The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to checkout a repository from visual svn server in my server to tortoise svn in my computer. But trying to check out gives me error 'Error running context: The requested address is not valid in its context.

Comment: Try checkout with command line tools (`svn co http://...`) may be it provide more detailed info

Comment: just try to ping host of repo - it can be unreacheable or not resolvable

Answer (score 7):

To fix this problem, delete data on the dir C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Subversion and restart your PC

Comment: You saved my day! I was clearing all the caches in TortoiseSVN settings, restarted PC, was trying command-line svn tool, but only crearing that folder helped. P.S. No restart was required, at least not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and the solution was obvious once I saw it.  In the network setup on the Tortoise client, the default port is set to 0. Make sure it is 80, or whichever the HTTP port the SVN server is listening on.